# On $[0,1] $ $, 100$ points are chosen at random. $X_1$- number of chosen point between $\frac{1}{5}$

Tags: probability, random-variables

On $[0,1] $ $, 100$ points are chosen at random.(This probably means, uniformly, I can only assume, no other context is given, so let's pressume what seems most natural.)

$X_1$- number of chosen point between $\frac{1}{5}$

$X_2$- number of chosen points between $(\frac{1}{2},1)$

Find: CDF of $X_1$,$X_2$, $E(X_1)$ $D(X_2)$-variance

I'm having trouble mathematically modeling these variables, much less finding the CDF, anyone done something similar to this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you familiar with the binomial distribution?  For the first one, you have a $p=0.2$ (going along with the uniform distribution assumption, which I think is fair; you also have to assume independence of the points).  and $n=100$.  Those are the 2 parameters for a binomials.  $X_2$ will work the same way, with $p=0.5$.

So every point location can be seen as a Bernoulli experiment.  The distribution over the sample space (position in sample space given by $k$) is given as
$$P(k,n,p)={n\choose k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$$

Comment: I am quite aware of this, could you type out the answer in full so I can be completely sure ?

Comment: Aren't $X_1$ and $X_2$ dependent ?

Comment: @JimLowe, sure, but dependence does not change single-variable probability distributions.